# Trying to group all the values in one common array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to store in one array all the different inputs that I get from  in the parent component as it is rendered 4 times. At the moment I reached the stage where I can store the value in an array(check the child component) but the method creates 4 different arrays where it stores the different values of each different input. In few words I get 4 arrays (ex. [3,5], [4,8], [9,8], [2,3]. I would like to group all the values in one common array(ex. [ 3,5,4,8,9,8,2,3]. I have tried few things but did not work out. Could anyone help me in fixing this problem?Thanks

Parent Component

```
                        <div className="bet-list">
                            <ol>
                                <p>NAME</p>
                                {
                                    bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.name}
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ol>
                            <ul>
                                <p>ODDS</p>
                                {
                                    bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.odds[4].oddsDecimal}
                                            <div className="stake-margin">
                                                <Stake />
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Child Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Stake() {
    const [stakes, setStakes] = useState([]);
    const [singleStake, setSingleStake] = useState("");

    const addStake = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setStakes([...stakes, singleStake]);
        // setSingleStake("");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(stakes);
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={addStake}>
                <input
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: "40px",
                        width: "50px"
                    }}
                    value={singleStake}
                    onChange={(e) => setSingleStake(e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    name="stake"
                    placeholder="stake"
                    required
                />
            </form>
            <div>
                {stakes?.map((stake, idx) => (
                    <p key={idx}>{stake}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Stake;
```

Comment: May I ask why do you want to group all value in a common array? Because the stakes have no limit length or so, it seems there is no way to separate them once the stacks are stored together.

Comment: So, to my understanding, you want to make the state *persistent* through renders. You want to keep all the previous states in an array. You should use something like [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) or [localStorage](https://medium.com/@siobhanpmahoney/local-storage-in-a-react-single-page-application-34ba30fc977d) in that case.

Comment: I've tried to implement localstorage but I get the same problem. I'll try to recode the compnent with localstorage and post another question. Thanks for following me. I'll do it in ten mins.